# Remove text (& brackets) from a string with regex

Tags: regex

It's easy when you understand...unfortunately, I don't! I will deeply appreciate you if you can guide me to the answer, thanks.

I want to capture a string, using just regex, but remove any text that's within brackets. e.g.

This is a typical string...

```
<td class="rc_entry_alt" >Mark Anthony (IRE)</td>
```

I can capture "Mark Anthony (IRE)" very easily. I'm currently using...

```
/<td class="rc_entry(_alt)?" >.*<\/td>/
```

What i'd like is to remove the " (IRE)". Note the preceding space prior to the first bracket. I want to remove this too. Also, the text between the `(` and `)` will vary, e.g. USA, ITY, FR, etc. It should look like this...

```
Mark Anthony
```

I've no doubt it's very simple, and yet it eludes me. Thanks for your time :)

n.b. The stuff in brackets isn't always there. Sometimes I get what I want with the original code I mentioned.

Comment: Edit your post to include your current regex, and then we can suggest modifications.

Comment: From the looks of it, I would suggest using an HTML library that supports node traversal/manipulation... if not, please search on SO as this sort of regex ("the kind to get stuff out of HTML elements") is quite common. Note that extracting the node content and then removing the "(stuff)" can be viewed as two separate steps.

Comment: I apologise. Believe me, posting this is lame I know, but it's just one thing I can't find the answer to, no matter how much i've searched. Sorry, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so remove the HTML first, then do something like this to remove the (...) part:

```
\s+\(.*?\)
```

If you know the (...) part is the very last thing in the string (i.e. there's nothing after it), you can use this to check that it's at the end, too:

```
\s+\(.*?\)$
```

Just use a Regex find and replace function, find the expression above, and replace with nothing.

Comment: Thankyou very much.  It works. I see how this path corrects the problem. I'm enlightened. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Regexp would look something like that. The acutal Syntax depends on your programming language / tool.

First you need to match the `<td ..>` part. Then you capute everything upto `(`. then to be sure match everything in brackets followed by `</td>`.

```
/<td[^>].*>\([^(]*\)(.*)</td>/
```

You should read the Book: Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey Friedl.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the recommendation. :)